# When is a principal bundle with group $G \times H$ the product of a principal bundle with group $G$ and one with group $H$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

In general, it is not true that a fiber bundle with a product fiber is the product of two fiber bundles with the factors as fibers (think of vector bundles). However, I read somewhere that every 2-torus bundle is the product of two circle bundles, and I do not know why. So, my question is both why is this true in the torus case and what can we say in the more general case of the product of two Lie groups?

Comment: Using the letters $G,H$ for the base when they are usually used to denote groups is not ideal. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry I actually did mean the groups it was my use of *over* that was wrong.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, even in the torus case.  For example, there is a principal $T^2$ bundle $T^2\rightarrow SU(3)\rightarrow SU(3)/T^2$ which doesn't seem to be a product in any sense of the word.

Comment: So you mean the pullback by the diagonal map on the base of the product of two bundles over the same base?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I just mean the product in the category of principal bundles over a fixed base.

Comment: @JasonDeVito can you expand on your example?

Comment: @JackFres:  I wasn't thinking about the product in the sense you and Ted are discussing.  I *do* think my example is a product in that sense, though I haven't yet actually written down the relevant diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a principal bundle with structure group $G\times H$ is always a product in the sense given in the comments.

Specifically, we have the following

**Proposition:**  Suppose $P\xrightarrow{\pi} M$ is a principal $G\times H$ bundle.  Then there is a principal $G$ bundle $P_G\rightarrow M$ and a principal $H$-bundle $P_H\rightarrow M$ with the property that $P$ is isomorphic to the pullback of the $G\times H$ bundle $P_G\times P_H\rightarrow M\times M$ under the diagonal map $M\rightarrow M\times M$.

Before proving this, let me just mention some notation I'll be using.  I will identity $G$ with $G\times \{e\}$ and $H$ with $\{e\}\times H$ (where $e$ denotes the identity of either group.).  Given $p\in P$, I'll write multiplication on the left: for $(g,h)\in G\times H$, I'll write $(g,h)\ast p =  ghp$, where I am thinking of $g$ as $(g,1)$ and $h$ as $(1,h)$.  The $G$, $H$, and $(G\times H)$ orbits through $p$ will be denoted by $pG$, $pH$, and $p(G\times H)$ respectively.  The letters $g$ and $h$ will always indicate members of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

Proof:  Consider first the manifold $P_G:= P/H$.  This is a smooth manifold upon which $G$ natural acts via $g\ast (pH) = gpH$.  This action is again free, and $(P_G)/G$ is naturally diffeomorphic to $M$.  In particular, the quotient map $P_G\rightarrow (P_G)/H\cong M$ is a principal $G$-bundle.  Similarly, one can consider the manifold $P_H:=P/G$.

Form the principal $(G\times H)$-bundle $P_G\times P_H$ over $M\times M$, and let $i:M\rightarrow M\times M$ denote the diagonal map $i(m) = (m,m)$.

We claim that $i^\ast(P_G\times P_H) \cong P$.

Then one can easily verify that the map $\phi:P\rightarrow i^\ast(P_G\times P_H)$ given by $\phi(p) = (\pi(p), pH, pG)$ is a $(G\times H)$ equivariant map covering the identity.

Proving $\phi$ is a bijection is a bit more difficult, so I'll provide the proof.

*Injectivity*:  Assume $\phi(p) = \phi(p')$, so $pH = p'H$ and $pG = p' G$.  This means that there is an $h\in H$ and a $g\in G$ with $p = hp'$ and $p = gp' $.  Thus, $hp' = gp'$, so $(g^{-1}h)p' = p'$.  This tells us that $g^{-1}h = (e,e)$, so $g = h$.  However, $g\in G$ and $H\in H$, and $G\cap H = \{(e,e)\}$, so we must have $g = h = e$. Thus, $p = p'$, as desired.

*Surjectivity*:  Suppose $(m, p_1 H, p_2 G)\in i^\ast(P_G\times P_H)$.  Because $p_1(G\times H) = m= p_2(G\times H)$, there is a $(g,h)\in G\times H$ with $gp_1 = hp_2$.  We can rewrite this as $h^{-1} p_1  = g^{-1}p_2$.

Consider the point $g^{-1} p_2 \in P$.  We claim that $\phi(g^{-1}p_2) = (m, p_1 H, p_2 G)$.  Since $\phi(g^{-1}p_2) = (\pi(g^{-1} p_2), g^{-1} p_2 H, g^{-1}p_2 G)$, we will verify the equality $$(\pi(g^{-1} p_2), g^{-1} p_2 H, g^{-1}p_2 G) = (m, p_1 H, p_2 G)$$ one coordinate at a time.

For the first coordinate, we find $\pi(g^{-1} p_2) = \pi(p_2) = m$, as desired.  For the third coordinate, we have $g^{-1} p_2 G = p_2 G$ as desired.

The second coordinate works as follows:  $g^{-1} p_2 H = h^{-1} p_1 H = p_1 H.$
$\square$

Comment: I was implicitly assuming $M$ is a smooth manifold in the above because that's what I usually think about, but the same proof works in the topological category.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very precise answer!